# What is the differences between Nothing or Any in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to know the differences between Nothing and Any

I have sealed class

```
sealed class Result<out R>() {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val errorMsg: String) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

And this is the usage of Result class

```
fun <T>test(data: T) : Result2<T> {
    return Result2.Error("error")
}
```

If I change this

```
data class Error(val errorMsg: String) : Result<Nothing>()
```

To this

```
data class Error(val errorMsg: String) : Result<Any>()
```

An error occurs in test function (error message below)

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Result<T>
Found: Result.Error
```

Can type Nothing replace generic T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nothing` is a class, that have no instances.
In kotlin type system `Nothing` is considered as a subclass of all other class.
`Any` is completely opposite. Every other class considered as subclass of `Any`.

In you function `test` you declared `T` as lower bound. But `Any` can't match, because it is lower then any other `T`. Remember: `Any` is parent for any other class.

Also take a loot at great blog post about kotlin type system: https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/the-beauty-of-kotlin-typing-system-7a2804fe6cf0